# Associating Photo to Feature ID in ArcPad

Tags: arcpad

I'm trying to associate a photo to a feature in ArcPad.

Currently I have three photo fields for my feature layer, titled "Poles".
Essentially, I have field technicians taking three different photos for each utility pole they come across, "COMM_PHOTO, POLE_PHOTO, and TAG_PHOTO" are the three different fields for the photos in the Poles feature layer. The problem I am facing is that when they take the photos with the tablet camera, it is saving all of them as simply the field name plus the photo number in succession, such as COMM_PHOTO_001, or COMM_PHOTO_002, which describes the field and the photo that was taken in succession with the camera.

What I need is the field photo to be COMM_PHOTO, POLE_PHOTO, AND TAG_PHOTO plus the unique pole_id which is populated in the Poles layer.

Anyone have a way of doing this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out. seems like they are trying to keep this a mystery.. must be a lot of others who could really use this functionality. Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You may create a custom button within you collection form that calls a vb script on click event that pulls the feature id value (defined within a text box) and assigns it to a variable which you may then concatenate with you photo name variable:

Here is the basic vb logic to get a control value:

```
Dim objTheLayer, objTheForm, objEFPageControls
Set objTheLayer = Application.Map.Layers.item(layerName)
Set objTheForm = objTheLayer.Forms(1)

Set objEFPageControls= objTheForm.Pages(pageName).Controls
objTheForm.Pages(pageName).activate

idVal=objEFPageControls("txtIDValue").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling the ID out of a TextField is what i already thought about too. But you are missing the point how you can set that variable to the filename prefix which is stored in the ArcPadPrefs.apx.

You need a way to access that ArcPadPref after you took the photo. But even if you do so, you cant save the changes in the apx because ArcPad is already running.

I do not think that there is a way to solve this problem.